# Draw sprites from JPG with D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, css-sprites

I've got a scatter plot chart that consists of several hundred points, each point represented by an image. The coordinates as well as the image filenames are loaded via AJAX. It works as intended, but with this approach every single image is loaded by itself, resulting in several hundred requests. This is the code I'm using right now and that's working fine:

```
function position(dot) {
    dot .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("width", function(d) { return d.r * 5; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return d.r * 10; })
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.ImageFile })
    ;
}
```

So, to speed things up, I dynamically create a sprite image file on the server. This also works well. But I can't find out how to load that sprite and access the single images within that sprite. I came across `clipPath`, but I'm obviously using it incorrectly:

```
function position(dot) {
    dot .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("width", function(d) { return d.r * 5; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return d.r * 10; })
        .attr("clipPath", function(d) { return d.i*140 + " 0 140 200"; })
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return 'mySprite.jpg'; })
    ;
}
```

**So, how can I use a sprite image created dynamically on the server within my D3.js code?**

My overall code is somewhat based on this example: https://github.com/mbostock/bost.ocks.org/blob/gh-pages/mike/nations/index.html

Comment: Slightly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390158/generate-clippaths-for-multiple-elements-in-d3-js. Note that the attribute is called `clip-path` not `clipPath`.